# mapserver vrt et mapfile : file not found or unsupported format

Tags: mapserver, csv, vrt

I try to create a mapfile with data in a csv file. I have failed to draw the layer with a Virtual Format and a OGR connectiontype directly in the mapfile. So I have decided to store the connection in a different file like here http://mapserver.org/input/vector/VirtualSpatialData.html#steps-for-display
mapfile :

```
LAYER
CONNECTION "C:\blabla\basol_auv.ovf"
CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
DATA "test"
METADATA
    "wms-srs" "2154"
    "wms-title" "test"
END
NAME "pollution"
TYPE POINT
CLASS
    NAME "pollution"
    STYLE
        SYMBOL "pollution"
        SIZE 10
    END #----fin style
  END #-----fin class
END #-----fin layer sols pollués
```

basol_auv.ovf :

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
   <OGRVRTLayer  name='test'>
    <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="0">C:\OSGeo4W\Apache\htdocs\data\test.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>test</SrcLayer>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <GeometryField encoding='PointFromColumns' x='A' y='B'/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
```

I have a new error message :

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'pollution'.
>               msOGRFileOpen(): OGR error. Open failed for OGR connection in layer `pollution'.  File not found or unsupported format.
>
> I dont'know what to do to verify if it is a matter of path or format.

ogrinfo command gives the correct answer : ogrinfo basol_auv.ovf test

Comment: Try full file path in CONNECTION.

Comment: yes that was "just" that. Thank you. I updated the code.